# Рамка UIView после применения CGAffineTransformMakeRotation и CGAffineTransformScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, transform

При повороте смартфона, на экране одновременно вращается и масштабируется прямоугольная рамка UIView. Известно, что после трансформаций иметь дело со свойством frame становится сложным из-за того, что несмотря на размеры рамки, которую мы видим на экране, во frame размеры записаны совсем другие, а именно самые крайние точки для описания в него прямоугольника. Как мне найти настоящие ширину и высоту после трансформаций?

Comment: вы до сих пор свой трансформ мучаете :( это все делается синусами и косинусами

Comment: честно говоря в математике не силен, вот и мучаю трансформ

Comment: я в ваш предыдущий вопрос кода скинул. может поможет

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, попробуйте воспользоваться свойствами слоя. `Frame` не всегда совпадает с позицией слоя. Попробуйте `[myView.layer.presentationLayer frame]`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height
[image: bounds vs frame]